# How to color the first row in a named range using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub color_range(namedRange As String)
    Dim rangeData As Range
    Set rangeData = ThisWorkbook.Names(namedRange).RefersToRange
    Range(rangeData.Cells(1, 1), rangeData.Cells(1, rangeData.Columns.Count)).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(0, 63, 114)
End Sub
```

Running the above sub i get a subscript out of bounds error.
What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Which specific line is raising the error?

Comment: `rangeData.Rows(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 63, 114)`

Answer (score 1):

When using RGB colors use the color property vs colorindex.

```
Range(rangeData.Cells(1, 1), rangeData.Cells(1, rangeData.Columns.Count)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 63, 114)
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`rangeData` already refers to the `Range` you want to work with; try retrieving its first row - but because `Range.[_Default]` returns a `Variant` the rest of the call will be implicitly late-bound unless you pull the result into another local variable, like this:

```
Dim firstCell As Range
Set firstCell = rangeData.Cells(1, 1) ' implicit: Range.[_Default].Item(1, 1)
```

Now you get compile-time validation for member calls against the `firstCell`, and this should work (untested):

```
firstCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 63, 114)
```

However none of this would fix an "index out of range" / "subscript out of bounds" error thrown here:

```
Set rangeData = ThisWorkbook.Names(namedRange).RefersToRange
```

Verify that the supplied `namedRange` exists in `ThisWorkbook.Names` :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a sheet in front of the range, so running it on another sheet will give you an error. It is better to work based on the designated range.

```
Sub color_range(namedRange As String)
    Dim rangeData As Range
    Set rangeData = ThisWorkbook.Names(namedRange).RefersToRange
    'Range(rangeData.Cells(1, 1), rangeData.Cells(1, rangeData.Columns.Count)).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(0, 63, 114)
    rangeData.Resize(1, rangeData.Columns.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 63, 114)
End Sub
```